# is sql exam 70-451 simpler than 70-433? or vise-versa?

Tags: sql-server

I am setting to take the Microsoft sql server exams 70-451 and 70-433 and wanted to know is there an order they should be taken in?

Intuitively I would thing the 70-433 exam should go first but read reviews where people passed it last.

Any thoughts on how to best take these two exams?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about specific certification exams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MCTS certification is easier than MCITP (PRO) certification exams. According to microsoft learning [Microsft SQL Server Certification](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/cert-sql-server.aspx) (check the certification paths), MCTS is a pre requisite to MCITP cerfication.

The path to be taken for an MCITP Database Developer SQL Server 2008 is MCTS SQL Server 2008 Database Development (Exam 70-433) followed by Exam 70-451.

MCITP stands for 'Microsoft Certified IT Professional' while MCTS stands for 'Microsoft Certified Technology Specialist'.

Comment: +1 Interesting, small nitpick: I think you mean 70-433 were you write 70-431?

Answer (score 1):

One is PRO and the other is TS (technology specialist.)  I've done one of them, although I can't remember which.  I don't know which one is more advanced and you can't really tell from the Microsoft certification pages.

And if we can't tell the difference, it seems unlikely that a recruiter will be able to.